# Swapping JButtons in Java

Tags: java, image, swing, jbutton

I made an array list of strings and assigned an image to each string. Then, I randomized these images. I want to now make a method that swaps one button to the button adjacent to it, but I have no idea how to do this. Any suggestions about how to go about it? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

First suggestion: **Don't**. Don't swap JButtons as you're making things much harder than they need to be. Instead if possible swap **images** or more specifically *ImageIcons*, and this can be easily done using the JButton method, `setIcon(...)`.

It almost sounds as if you're trying to create a memory game, and if so there are plenty of examples of just this sort of thing to be found on this site, at least one created by me.

As always in these sorts of things, first concentrate on the program's ***model***, that is, its logical underpinnings, and only after getting that working, apply it to the program's ***view*** or its GUI representation of the model's state.